# what's wrong with this regex for password rules

Tags: regex

I'm trying for at least 2 letters, at least 2 non letters, and at least 6 characters in length:

```
^.*(?=.{6,})(?=[a-zA-Z]*){2,}(?=[0-9@#$%^&+=]*){2,}.*$
```

but that misses the mark on many levels, yet I'm not sure why.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by misses the mark?

Comment: As an aside, if you do use regexes, why not use [^a-zA-Z] to denote a non-character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, here's what's wrong with your regex:

First, the `.*` (dot-star) at the beginning consumes the whole string.  Then the first lookahead, `(?=.{6,})` is applied and fails because the match position is at the end of the string.  So the regex engine starts backtracking, "taking back" characters by moving the match position backward one character at a time and reapplying the lookahead.  When it's taken back six characters, the first lookahead succeeds and the next one is applied.

The second lookahead is `(?=[a-zA-Z]*)`, which means "at the current match position, try to match zero or more ASCII letters."  The match position is still six characters back from the end of the string, but it doesn't matter; the lookahead will always succeed no matter you apply it, because it can legally match zero characters.  Also, the letters can be anywhere in the string, so the lookahead has to accommodate whatever intervening non-letters there might be.

Then you have `{2,}`. It's not part of the lookahead subexpression because it's outside the parentheses.  In that position, it means the lookahead has to succeed two or more times, which makes no sense.  If it succeeded once, it will succeed any number of times, because it's being applied at the same position every time.  Some regex flavors treat it as an error when you apply a quantifier to a lookahead (or to any other zero-width assertion, eg, lookbehind, word boundary, line anchors).  Most flavors seem to ignore the quantifier.

Then you have another lookahead that will always succeed, and another useless quantifier.  Finally, the dot-star at the end re-consumes the six characters the first dot-star had to relinquish.

I think this is what you were trying for:

```
^
(?=.{6})
(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})
(?=(?:[^0-9@#$%^&+=]*[0-9@#$%^&+=]){2})
.*$
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to not only spoon up a working RegEx, but to explain great detail what was wrong with the first one (which as you note is in fact the question)

Answer (score 10):

While this type of test can be done with a regex, it may be easier and more maintainable to do a non-regex check.  The regex to achieve this is fairly complex and a bit unreadable.  But the code to run this test is fairly straight forward.  For example take the following method as an implementation of your requirements (language C#)

```
public bool IsValid(string password) {
  // arg null check ommitted
  return password.Length >= 6 &&
         password.Where(Char.IsLetter).Count() > 2 &&
         password.Where(x => !Char.IsLetter(x)).Count() > 2;
}
```

Comment: Much clearer than any single regular expression that could do the same.

Comment: I agree.  While you might be able to crunch that down into a single line of regex, think of how long it would take you to do that as well as how long it would take you to change/debug it in the future.

Comment: There's no denying that a non-regex option would likely be better, but I'm tasked with "do as your told" --- I suspect this expression will be inserted into to a RegularExpressionValidator control on the web app.  We have a saying here "It is what it is"

Comment: @Ralph it really sucks when that happens. Is it possible for you to do multiple regex passes on the same string?  That is very doable in 3 short concise regex's.  One giant regex is just that giant.  The number of permutations you have to try is huge.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use regular expressions, try this one:

```
(?=.{6})(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9@#$%^&+=]*[0-9@#$%^&+=][^0-9@#$%^&+=]*[0-9@#$%^&+=])^.+$
```

This matches anything that is at least six characters long (`(?=.{6,})`) and does contain at least two alphabetic characters (`(?=[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])`) and does contain at least two characters of the character set `[0-9@#$%^&+=]` (`(?=[0-9@#$%^&+=][^0-9@#$%^&+=]*[0-9@#$%^&+=])`).

Comment: A shorter regexp which does the same almost the same way: ^(?=.{6}(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]).*[0-9@#$%^&+=].*[0-9@#$%^&+=]

Comment: But it’s less efficient because of unnecessary backtracking.