# regular expression for password

Tags: asp.net, regex

Please can some one give me regular expression for password with the following rules.

Password should be at least 7 characters long.
It should contain minimum 3 digits and one alphabetic character.
Password can accept numbers, alphabets, special characters any number of times except numbers should be minimum 3.

Comment: Why should I bother? You should at least pretend you are making the effort of writing one yourself!

Comment: I think people asking with out trying is why its down voted...  a good google search easily returns a few suggestions.

Comment: @BigBlondeViking - You have no idea if he tried to write a regex before asking the question.  It may have been that he tried and failed.  And as per ceejayoz answer, kavitha needs some help to step back from the problem in order to see the error of his ways.  Fitting that sort of thing into a google request is kinda hard

Comment: If he/she tried then provide an example of what they are doing... he might have the right regex and using JS and .Net code wrong... I was making an observation on why it was getting down-voted. i have not voted on this question yet since its not useful yet...

Answer (score 8):

Regular expressions aren't particularly good at ensuring that particular groups of characters appear a certain number of times. While it's probably possible - it would no doubt be convoluted and non-obvious.

If you're programming in .NET (C# or VB) you can use a simple validation function something like:

```
bool ValidatePasswordCompliance( string password )
{
    int countDigits = 0;
    int countAlpha  = 0;
    int countOthers = 0;
    foreach( char c in password )
    {
         countDigit += c.IsDigit ? 1 : 0;
         countAlpha += c.IsAlpha ? 1 : 0;
         countOther += !(c.IsAlpha || c.IsDigit) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return countDigits >= 3 && (countDigits + countAlpha + countOthers) >= 7;
}
```

If you're working with .NET 3.5 or higher, you could use LINQ to simplify this:

```
bool ValidatePasswordCompliance( string password )
{
    return password.Count() >= 7 &&
           password.Count( x => x.IsDigit ) >= 3;
}
```

Comment: I would note, that a real world password validation function may want to check for any reserved characters that are not valid as password characters - particularly if it is intended to work in a multi-language environment like the web.

Comment: Regex can be challenging and rewarding when you craft one that works well but not always the answer. Up vote for pragmatism.

Answer (score 4):

This is better suited to a validation function that checks your individual criteria one-by-one than an overly complicated regex.

If you're hellbent on using a regex, take a look at [this almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889703/whats-wrong-with-this-regex-for-password-rules)... but read the highest voted answer, not just the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions, while elegant if done right, are *not* fit for all purposes. I would suggest that this is one of the cases it is not suited for.

Don't get me wrong, you can do it with a single RE, but it's likely to be far more complex and hard to maintain than some simple procedural which checks the length and character classes.

Answer (score 1):

That said, there are some people out there who actually do it with regular expressions (although they too admit that it's complicated)

http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C4F005D3717

Answer (score 0):

You can check complexity with regex pretty easily, but its not an end all...

Good article on setting up the different complexities you are looking for:

http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

You also might want to run the password against a simple dictionary, to see if it can be bypassed by a dictionary attack.