# Reg expression required for strong password

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

Could anyone help me with a regex for a password with the following please.

include at least two of the following:

a lowercase letter

a capital letter

a number

a 'special character' (e.g. £, $, &, #)

Comment: *at least two of the following*... means that a password with two lowercase letters and two capital letters is valid (without numbers, etc.) is valid?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394092/regex-for-strong-password?rq=1) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254952/regular-expression-for-password?rq=1) or maybe even [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370015/regular-expression-for-password-validation?rq=1).

Comment: Sorry, the password should contain 2 of the 4 character groups i.e. a lowercase letter and a number or a capital letter and a number etc

Comment: A regex probably isn't the right tool for this job. The best regex I can think of for that would be an alternation of 12 distinct possibilities: lowercase followed by uppercase, uppercase followed by lowercase, lowercase followed by number, etc. And you have to define what a "special character" is. It would be easier to write some code to loop over the characters of the password and keep counts of each class.

Comment: @JohnBanks What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Oscar .Net 4 MVC - I have this working sort of in js (?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])^.* but fails in mvc regex attribute

Comment: Though it's not regex, there's a javascript password strength algorithm at the bottom of this js that may be useful to display in the browser and/or convert to another language: https://github.com/nak5ive/Form.PasswordStrength/blob/master/Source/Form.PasswordStrength.js

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. The OP wants to have at least `2` of the `4` requirements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Keith Thompson said in a comment, I don't think a single regex is worth here.

The following code will do what you want, and I think it is more readable, maintainable and easier to prove the correctness than a single regular expression:

```
string password = "123abc";
string[] regexes = new[]
    {
        "[a-z]", //any lowercase word
        "[A-Z]", //any uppercase word
        @"\d", //any digit
        @"\W" //special characters (or just [£$&#], adding the characters you want)
    };
bool isValid = regexes.Count(regex => Regex.IsMatch(password, regex)) >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I created a validationattribute and used Oscar's suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
^(?![a-z]*$|[A-Z]*$|\d*$|[\W_]*$).*$
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/effCmvehdx

The negative lookahead at the beginning will cause this to fail if the entire string is composed entirely of just one group.

Note that even though this fits your requirements, this is not a very good regex for a strong password.  You probably also want a length check and you may want to require at least three of those groups instead of two.

Comment: hmm.. am I missing something here? *include at least two of the following*... it means that `abcABC` or `abc123` have to be valid.

Comment: @OscarMederos: Yes, and they are. Where's the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was testing with Rad Software Regular Expression Designer, and it wasn't matching. I tested it with C# and worked. Could you edit your question so that I can remove my downvote?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, a regex is almost certainly not the right tool for this job. It's going to be much easier to write some code that iterates over the characters of the password, counting the number of characters in each class.

You haven't defined what a "special character" is. I'll assume that it means any character other than a letter or digit (which would include spaces and control characters). I'm also assuming that "letters" refers to just the 26 letters of the English alphabet -- which means that a non-English letter like `ñ` is a special character.

To take a simpler example, regexes aren't very good at expressing things like "foo and bar in either order"; you have to specify both order explicitly:

```
 foo.*bar|bar.*foo
```

In this case, you need 12 different choices. I *think* this is correct, but I haven't tested it.

```
[a-z].*[A-Z}|[A-Z].*[a-z}|[a-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-z]|[a-z].*[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^a-zA-Z0-9].*[a-z]|[A-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^a-zA-Z0-9].*[A-Z]|[0-9].*[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^a-zA-Z0-9].*[0-9]
```

This is an egrep-style or Perl-style regex. `grep` doesn't recognize `|` by default; if you need a `grep`-style regexp, replace each `|` by `\|`.

And if the requirements change, say requiring at least 3 out of 5 classes of characters, you'll need to completely rewrite the regex; you can't just tweak it.

Note that your requirements still permit `Aa`.